# Which possible models can I use to predict results from this dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, r, regression, predictive-modeling, cross-validation

I'm new at predicting things like this. I have a data set. The head of it is shown here:

[image]

I have yet another data set for the upcoming basketball games that are taking place soon with the score columns blank. I have to use the current data that I have that spans from 2010-2020 to predict what will happen soon. It's just that I have little knowledge of this and no experience in machine learning although i would be willing to learn.

Comment: what are you trying to predict ?  Please explain abbreviations in your data.